# Problem with meter sound

Tags: iphone, audio

i am using meter, when the sound is play on each level(change level rapidly), the application is crashed... end the eroor is too many files open, What will i do?

Comment: If we need to do something so that it will help you to do whatever you want I suggest you post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i am retrieve data from the data base and on each time, I was opening database and does not finilize database. When i wrote this so error has been removed:

```
sqlite3_reset(addStmt1);
sqlite3_finalize(addStmt1);
```